# how to give explicit type in type graphql for key-value pair object

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I am trying to give explicit type in type-graphql for key value pair. Here, key-value pair is declare like `[key: string]: string`, so it could be any type string type of key and value of string type, but key should be any. If I declare variable with this type then I can have object of like `{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}`, etc I can add any key-value pair in this. So, my question is how to give explicit type of this key-value pair in type graphql.
Below is my code:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Result {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  domainName?: string;

  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  uniqueIds?: string[];

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  resultKeyVal: { [key: string]: string };
}
```

I'm getting this error:
'Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for 'resultKeyVal' of 'Result' class.'

If you notice second field 'uniqueIds', there I'm able to provide explicit type, but if you notice third field 'resultKeyVal' then how should I give the explicit type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must create a custom [GraphQL Scalar](https://graphql.org/learn/schema).

Fortunately, the [graphql-scalars](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars) library already has the scalar `GraphQLJSONObject`:

1. Install `graphql-scalars`:

   ```
   npm install --save graphql-scalars
   ```
2. Update `Result` class:

   ```js
   // ...
   import { GraphQLJSONObject } from 'graphql-scalars';

   // Possible JSON value types
   export type JSONValue =
     | string
     | number
     | boolean
     | null
     | { [key: string]: JSONValue }
     | Array<JSONValue>;

   @ObjectType()
   export class Result {
     @Field({ nullable: true })
     domainName?: string;

     @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
     uniqueIds?: string[];

     // Update field
     @Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
     resultKeyVal?: { [key: string]: JSONValue };
   }
   ```