# CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I am getting this below error while accessing the graphQL.
Error:

Here I need `subStatus` as dynamic object. I have taken `ObjectType` type decorator to make it dynamic object but it seems something is wrong.

```
CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'subStatus' of 'UpdateEnrollmentInput' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?'
```

Here is InputType

```html
@InputType()
export class UpdateEnrollmentInput {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  account: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  dataSource: string;

  @Field()
  enrollmentId: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  enrollmentSourceId: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  enrollmentOperationId: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  vehicleId: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  status: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  organizationId: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  locationId: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  statusDescription: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  vin: string;

  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  dataService: string[];

  @Field(() => ObjectType, { nullable: true })
  subStatus: {};
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add more information. What is `ObjectType`? Are you using the decorator a type?

Comment: @CarloCorradini thank you for you reply. I have added the information.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic object? Moreover you cannot return `ObectType` directly

Comment: @CarloCorradini dynamic object is like we don't know the property name e.g { 'dynamicKey':'value'}.
what we can use in place of ObjectType

Comment: Ok, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73910019/6676781. It's exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you @CarloCorradini but the given solution is different from my requirement. I have multi level nested object. but yes I can see one clue there. Thank you.

Comment: The field is a simple JSON object, you can nest everything you ant there, even multiple (infinite) objects/arrays :)